# Scraper: Try skips code in while loop (Python)

Tags: python

I am working on my first scraper and ran into an issue. My scraper accesses a website and saves links from the each result page. Now, I only want it to go through 10 pages. The problem comes when the search results has less than 10 pages. I tried using a while loop along with a try statement, but it does not seem to work. After the scraper goes through the first page of results, it does not return any links on the successive pages; however, it does not give me an error and stops once it reaches 10 pages or the exception.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
links = []
page = 1
while(page <= 10):
    try:
        # Get information from the propertyInfo class
        properties = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "propertyInfo item"]'))
        # For each listing
        for p in properties:
             # Find all elements with a tags
             tmp_link = p.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a')
             # Get the link from the second element to avoid error
             links.append(tmp_link[1].get_attribute('href'))
        page += 1
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="paginador_siguiente"]/a').click())
    except ElementNotVisibleException:
        break
```

I really appreciate any pointers on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitely catching `ElementNotVisibleException` exception and stopping on it. This way you won't see any error message. The error is probably in this line:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="paginador_siguiente"]/a').click())
```

I assume lambda here should be a test, which is run until succeeded. So it shouldn't make any action like click. I actually believe that you don't need to wait here at all, page should be already fully loaded so you can just click on the link:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="paginador_siguiente"]/a').click()
```

This will either pass to next page (and `WebDriverWait` at the start of the loop will wait for it) or raise exception if no next link is found.

Also, you better minimize `try ... except` scope, this way you won't capture something unintentionally. E.g. here you only want to surround next link finding code not the whole loop body:

```
# ...
while(page <= 10):
    # Scrape this page
    properties = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(...)
    for p in properties:
         # ...
    page += 1

    # Try to pass to next page
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="paginador_siguiente"]/a').click()
    except ElementNotVisibleException:
        # Break if no next link is found
        break
```

Comment: This partially helped. I think I have a bigger issue with the website itself, which wrecks my code. I will update soon. Thanks.